# Bootstrap: Setting col 1 `label and display` inline of col 2 `label and input`

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Say I have the form layout needing to be inline with both columns

```
LabelFor DisplayNameFor  |   LabelFor DropDownListFor
```

I can get the LabelFor my DropDownListFor to show properly (inline), but now my left column is out of wack and can't find anything to match the right as the left column doesn't have a input.

There a better way to solve this other than changing padding?

Code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>label 1</label>
            <label>display read only for label 1</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <label>label 2</label>
                <select class="form-control">select stuff</select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use flexbox to center align the content, or just make the columns equal height.

Add a class `.row-eq-height` to your row, then set `display: flex` on this class.
Using `align-items` will vertically center the column content to the height of the highest column. Omitting this setting will make the columns actually equal height.

```css
.col-xs-3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.row-eq-height {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>label 1</label>
        <label>display read only for label 1</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <label>label 2</label>
          <select class="form-control">select stuff</select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
</div>
```